# How to view my feed on Medium

Tags: rss, medium

Medium (medium.com) is a popular blogging platform. I’ve started following a bunch of authors, but I don’t know where to view a list of new posts by those authors, in chronological order (think RSS feed). Is there even such a feature on Medium’s site?

Answer (score 4):

The RSS feed for a particular author is located at

```
https://medium.com/feed/@authorname/
```

So, for instance, the feed for all of Jeff Jarvis's articles is at https://medium.com/feed/@jeffjarvis/

RSS feeds for a particular publication are similar, but it's based on the name of the publication without the @ sign. For instance:

```
https://medium.com/feed/mit-media-lab
```

([source](https://help.medium.com/hc/en-us/articles/214874118-Where-are-RSS-feeds-))

There's also the undocumented tag feed:

```
https://medium.com/feed/tag/lolcats/
```

There doesn't appear to be a single feed for your whole reading list, however.

Comment: I want a feed (or a page on Medium) which lists new posts by *all* the authors I follow, in chronological order.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, Medium doesn't offer that. You *may* be able to do something with a third-party feed aggregation service.

Comment: Ah, sorry; missed that.

Answer (score -1):

Though it's not reverse chronological, there's this section for articles from people you follow: https://medium.com/stream/network